# How do I close a modal dialog when a link (internal or external) is selected and how do I set one or more exceptions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

Each time a visitor selects a link, I expect the dialog to disappear and page to scroll down to the specific - selected id (w/o refresh). Of course, I have to set some exceptions as well!

```
<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal6" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal6" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content fp">
      <button type="button" class="ol close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-times fa-2x red"></i></button>
      <div class="heading text-center">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Text</p>
        <footer class="f2 text-left wrap2">
          <a href="#home">link A</a>
          <a href="#bclass">link B</a>
          <a href="#gclass">link C</a>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we see what you have tried already?

Comment: you can add onclicks to the in-modal links to call hideDialog (or whatever you use), or you could monitor hashchange events and hide the modal if the new url fragment is not the modal itself.

Comment: @hudsond7 I've tried this:
<a href="http://www.example.com/" onclick="$('#myModal').modal('hide')">click</a>
and this:
$('a').click(function(){
  $('modal-selector').modal('hide')
})

Comment: @dandavis I'm not experienced enough with javascript so, I can't get it.

Comment: @JimL well the code you show to hudson7 looks about like what i was suggesting, have you double-checked all the selectors? i notice one is #myModal and one is basicModal6 and one is selecting <modal-selector> tags.

Comment: @dandavis Yes, I did, but maybe in a wrong way... Can you link them properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for internal links it will automatically redirect to the location, you just need to hide the div. You can do it by this:

If your links are static:

```
$(".modal a").click(function(){ 
  $(this).closest(".modal").modal("hide");
});
```

if dynamic:

```
$(document).on('click', '.modal a', function(){ 
  $(this).closest(".modal").modal("hide");
});
```

Alternatively, You can also add this onclick on links:

```
onclick='$(this).closest(".modal").modal("hide")'
```

for external links it will be redirected to the link, no worries there.

Comment: I just found that after refresh it brings an "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" and after then it doesn't work.

Comment: you have written it before jquery loads, include jquery script tag in the head, or write above scripts at the end of body. basically anywhere after jquery script tag.

Comment: Now that it's placed just before </body> sometimes works. You're right about the jQuery load but I can't find a solution that works for everything

Comment: Well, this is my website https://jimmydance.com. it seems that by removing the async (I have only one js) everything is fine but I want it async...

Comment: what do u mean by making it async? this operation doesn't take time,,

Comment: My js file (the only one) includes the jQ and loads async for better performance. So,  I removed the async temporarily until I find the trick!

Comment: And what if you want to except a modal from this function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.modal('hide');` like this:

```js
$('.gotTo').click(function(){
  var $this=$(this);
  $this.closest('.modal').modal('hide');
});
```

```css
.section{
  margin-bottom:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal6" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal6" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content fp">
      <button type="button" class="ol close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-times fa-2x red"></i></button>
      <div class="heading text-center">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Text</p>
        <footer class="f2 text-left wrap2">
          <a href="#home" class="gotTo">link A</a>
          <a href="#bclass" class="gotTo">link B</a>
          <a href="#gclass" class="gotTo">link C</a>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="#basicModal6" role="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>
<div id="home" class="section">home</div>
<div id="bclass" class="section">bclass</div>
<div id="gclass" class="section">gclass</div>
```