# Except a modal from closing when click on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

Following these [intructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35023070/4491544) does what I need but what if I want to except/prevend some of the modals from following this rule?

```
$(".modal a").click(function(){ $(this).closest(".modal").modal("hide");});
```

Comment: Change the selector so it doesn't match the modals that you want to exclude. Maybe give them a class, and use `:not(.class)` in the selector.

Comment: Provide more specifics and relevant modal details along with code you use now

Comment: @Barmar Can you edit the snippet above in the question? Sorry, I'm not that familiar with jQ. Thanx

Comment: @charlietfl I added the snippet in the question. Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give all the modals that you want to exclude a class, like `class="noclose"`. Then add that to the selector.

```
$(".modal:not(.noclose) a").click(function(){ 
    $(this).closest(".modal").modal("hide");
});
```